# Detecting when a message is sent in a server

Tags: c#, discord, dsharp+

I'm trying to make a Discord Bot with DSharp+ that deletes all messages sent in a server during a certain timeframe. However, when looking through the DSharp+ API and extensive research, I could not find any way to have the bot detect if a message is sent and decide whether to delete it. How would I go about doing this, if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSharpPlus has a MessageCreated event. Subscribe the event and it'll invoke when a message is created. Be aware this also gets invoked for DM Messages as well, but there's likely some property you can null check.

Docs: https://dsharpplus.emzi0767.com/api/DSharpPlus.DiscordClient.html#DSharpPlus_DiscordClient_MessageCreated

Note: Discord won't let you bulk delete messages older than 2 weeks

Comment: You can delete messages older than 2 weeks old. Bulk deleting those messages however is restricted.